# How to hook up UIApplicationDelegate in MobileSubstrate

Tags: iphone, ios, hook

I want to hook up `UIApplicationDelegate:applicationDidEnterBackground`, but the system cannot find and install this hook.

**My code is as follows:**

```
IMP original_UIApplicationDelegate_applicationDidEnterBackground;
void replaced_UIApplicationDelegate_applicationDidEnterBackground(UIApplicationDelegate * self,SEL cmd, UIApplication *application)
{
    NSLog(@"==========applicationDidEnterBackground==========");
    original_UIApplicationDelegate_applicationDidEnterBackground(self, cmd, application);    
}
```

And then I call `MSHookMessageEx()` to install it. It doesn't work, though.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this syntax (and given the lack of responses, I suspect others are not). Are you using a particular framework other than standard Objective-C and Cocoa Touch?